# CSS Selector Not Working IN IE10

Tags: css, css-selectors, internet-explorer-10

I have a CSS selector like this

```
table[id^="tblBody_"] tbody tr td input[type="checkbox"]
{
    margin-top:-3px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="tblBody_tblApplicationWizardPageDetail">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input id="chkDisplayedBit" type="checkbox"/>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I have to apply this css on checkbox which exist in table cell where table id starts with `tblBody_`

this thing working fine in IE8 but not in IE10

Comment: Can you post your html?

Comment: are there any other check boxes are there

Comment: it works man, tested on standards and quirks mode

Comment: Just a suggestion... You might wanna rethink how you set your id and class attributes.  That is and ugly selector, you could simplify your design.

Comment: @rahul it would be better if you paste your code on http://jsbin.com/ or something similar, because I'm pretty sure that almost all the answers provided work.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not in the selector, as you can see e.g. by adding `outline: solid red` inside the rule. And setting a positive margin works. The problem seems to be in the way IE deals with a negative margin on the checkbox element. I don’t know whether actual IE 8 has this problem too, but IE 8 emulation mode in IE 10 has it.

The simple workaround is to use relative positioning instead of negative margin:

```
position: relative; top: -3px;
```

Comment: i tried ur solutions and it's still not working but if i give id to my checkbox style is applying but i want to apply css through my selector

Comment: @rahul, did you try exactly  replacing `margin-top:-3px;` by the code I suggested? How did you infer that it does not work? A displacement of 3 pixels is difficult to see, but if you try `-30px` instead, the effect is very clear.

Answer (score 1):

if your html is similar to the following snippet, it will work:

```
<table id="tblBody_32">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: are you sure about 32? Why not 33 ;-)?

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        *{ margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
        table[id^="tblBody_"]{ border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0; margin: 20px auto; width: 200px; }
        table[id^="tblBody_"] tbody tr td{ border:1px solid #ddd; width: 90px;padding: 5px;  }
        table[id^="tblBody_"] tbody tr td input[type="checkbox"] { margin-left: 20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="tblBody_abc">        
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="hobbit" id="hobbit"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I use this, it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
E[foo^="bar"]
```

> an E element whose "foo" attribute value begins exactly with the
>   string "bar"

```
selector level 3
```

and in [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com) they have written IE 10.0 supports css3 selector [see here](http://caniuse.com/#search=selectors) 
an same by [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#attribute_selectors) IE 10 supports attribute selectors

if everything not works use [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) is a JavaScript utility that emulates CSS3 pseudo-classes and attribute selectors in Internet Explorer 6-8 []surely works in IE10.